# How do you process large amounts of data without using a database?

Tags: php, arrays, highcharts

I am loading data from 365 csv files into the highstock graphing api. I am using PHP to read through the csv files and create arrays to hold the information. However I've encountered the:

> **Fatal error:** Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted

How do I work around this?

---

Hoping to create this graph:

> http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/compare

Comment: It's not possible to provide a workaround until you provide a real task you're solving. PS: does "allow php to allocate more memory and install additional memory on the server" count as an answer though?

Comment: @zerkms What do you mean?

Comment: I mean - it's impossible to provide optimization advices unless the thorough task explanation is given. There is no silver bullet in optimization, every case is unique. PS: there are rules of thumb though, like: keep the data in memory as less as possible and remove as soon as it's not required anymore

Comment: Ok, so you just need more information about my case?

Comment: we need an information about task you're solving. At the moment the question looks like: I tried to bake some cookies but failed. What have I done wrong?

Comment: The code provided is not a task explanation. A task explanation is "what you have and what you want to achieve" (in an essay form, not a code)

Comment: my crazy idea is to just allocate more memory. hardware resources are cheaper than human resources

Comment: @zerkms I explained that above no?  I am taking data from csv files and putting them into the highstock api. In order to extract the data I am creating PHP arrays.

Comment: @Willow: does a single csv fit into the memory? Can you send requests to the API one after another? So that you've read/processed one CSV, sent a request, `unset()` all arrays and repeat the same with the 2nd and so on?

Comment: @zerkms: From my understanding (but this is only my first time with highstock, so I could be wrong) all the data must be loaded in at once. The graph is displayed through jQuery. Each csv file is a little over 1MB. There will be 365 files eventually.

Comment: @Willow: so all 365 1mb files represent a single graph?

Comment: Correct. I'll edit above to add info on the graph.

Comment: Can I somehow use local storage to help me?  I've not yet worked with local storage so I am unfamiliar with exactly how to utilize it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of representing everything in memory as arrays it might be better just to go straight to json files with it. I'm going to make the assumption that the data you need is a 2 dimensional multidimensional array that contains a timestamp +  6 floating point fields.

Without knowing a lot of detail about how the information has to be served up to the charting api here is a first stab.

```
$tmpFile = tempnam("tmp/","highchart_");
$out = fopen($tmpFile, "w");
// we are not going to use json encode because it requires us to hold the array in memory. 
fputs($out, "[");
for($i=0;$i<count($files);$i++){
    if (($handle = fopen($files[$i], "r")) !== FALSE) {
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            // You may be able to get arround the timestamp calculation by just saying
            $timestamp = strtotime($data[0]." ".$data[1]);
            fputs($out, "[".(int)$timestamp.",".(float)$data[2].",".
                            (float)$data[3].",".(float)$data[4].",".(float)$data[5].",".(float)$data[13]."]");
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
}
fputs($out, "]");
fclose($out);
```

Now the file at `$tmpFile` would contain a json encoded array which you can then just use readfile or fpassthru to get to the browser.  Also I would urge you to use some sort of caching mechanism for this instead of just storing them in a temp file. +67MB of data is quite a beefy amount to chugging through with each request.

Comment: Fantastic idea. I think the graphing api prefers json files.  I tried to avoid them because I have never used json before. It talks about the json setup here: `http://docs.highcharts.com/#preprocesssing-data-from-a-file$3`

Comment: The jabber that is going over the wire on the jsfiddle attached to the example you posted used json. and the way that I have this structured there is no extraneous whitespace to eat up bandwidth when going across the wire to the browser.

Comment: Extreme thanks for your help.  I've been working on this for three days and it needs to be finished this evening. (>_<;)  I loaded your code into the php file.  How would I use readfile() to make sure the json tmp file was created properly?

Comment: `readfile($tmpFile);` readfile creates a pipe directly from the input file to the output buffer for php so it won't overrun your memory... just make sure you aren't in an ob_start block and you should be free and clear of memory issues.

Comment: for simple debugging you may find it easier to throw a ."\n" at the end of the fputs in the loop... as it is now it's going to give you a single line string about 10,000 miles long.

Comment: Ok, ran it through first try and got a never-ending page of `Warning: fputs(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in....`

Comment: That means you can't write to `/tmp/` make a place on your server where apache is allowed to write to and substitue the path prefix in the tmpname call

Comment: I hate to completely not understand, but what is apache? Once I finish this code I will be giving it to someone else to put on their server.  Will they need to change any settings on their server?

Comment: Apache is a webserver, one I had assumed that you where using. If not then how are you running this now... from the command line on a window box or do you have a webserver that you are running it through.

Comment: I am loading it onto my professor's server through ftp.  Each student is given space for projects.

Comment: So you will need to create a directory in your webspace and give it read write and execute permissions. ( I would make it right next to where you are hosting this php file). Then you can change the tmpname call to read `tempnam(__DIR__."/highchart_");` This will make it where the webserver (which is who is running php) tries to write these files it will have the permissions to do so.

Comment: What are the default permissions when you create a directory?  Before I had created one called tmp and put it next to the php file.

Comment: depends on the server ... your ftp client should tell you what the permissions are and give you the ability to change it. You using filezilla by chance?

Comment: I am using firefox ftp plugin.  I will ask my professor about the permissions and get back to you.

Comment: He's rather vague with his answer. He said, "You're opening a file that does not exist...use the document root."

Comment: Well if he's suggesting to use the document root you should be able to  use do `$tmpFile = tempnam($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/highchart_")`;

Comment: Bunch of `unset()` is redundant here. You can remove them and nothing would change.

Comment: @zerkms I think a lot of that can go away with concatenation of the date parts and a strtotime call... end game all she needs is a unixtimestamp representing the date for each data point

Comment: I understand that, but **why** do you perform `unset($year); unset(...);` ?

Comment: Thanks for your help guys.  I'm going to try to clean up the code then post it above.  The website is at: http://mm214.com/wshelley/graph/calc.php, so you can see all the errors going on.

Comment: I may have let you astray with the call to tmp_name in the above code... I have updated the answer, now it might show you some love

Comment: @zerkms okay I updated the answer to show the code the way I thought it should be instead of just talking about it in the comments

Comment: Oh wow!! It changed for the better! Orangepill I owe you so much!!

Comment: not a problem... hope the charting api can consume it as you hope.

Comment: Haha, I hope so too.  That is the next task. ^^